# RODBC "invalid character\n" error when using CASE WHEN statement

Tags: sql, r, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, rodbc

I'm attempting to execute a simple "if/then" statement on an Oracle SQL database using RODBC in R. The SQL statement works fine in SQL Developer v4.0.2.15 but throws an error when performing the same statement in R

```
sqlQuery(channel, "
select
    Variable1,
    Variable2,
    CASE WHEN Variable1 = 0 then 0 else 1 end as Var3
from schema.TABLE
where ROWNUM<100;
           "
  )
```

The error message (updated):

```
[1] "[1] "HY000 936 [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00936: missing expression\n"
[2] "[2] ...
```

The statement works fine when removing the CASE WHEN line, so the error must be in the CASE WHEN syntax.

Comment: Nevermind. Comment rescinded.

Comment: As well as the query in the error message not matching what you posted, the error itself isn't what you put in the title either. Can you verify that you have the code and error synchronised in the question? (I'd expect the 'invalid character' to be the semicolon at the end, but not sure if RODBC minds that like JDBC does, for example).

Comment: Alex P - I've corrected the error message

Comment: Try using DECODE(Variable1,0,0,1) instead of the case statement.

Comment: DECODE does work, thanks! You can also chain if/else statements so it handles flow control well:SELECT supplier_name,
DECODE(supplier_id, 10000, 'IBM',
                    10001, 'Microsoft',
                    10002, 'Hewlett Packard',
                    'Gateway') result
FROM suppliers;

Answer (score 3):

I've found a semicolon sometimes causes problems in cases like this.

```
> sqlQuery(con, "select case when dummy = 'X' then 1 else 0 end from dual")
  CASEWHENDUMMY='X'THEN1ELSE0END
1                              1

> sqlQuery(con, "select case when dummy = 'X' then 1 else 0 end from dual;")
[1] "HY000 911 [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00911: invalid character\n"                                       
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'select case when dummy = 'X' then 1 else 0 end from dual;'"
> close(con)
```

Comment: I solved my problem (an [R] RODBC::sqlQuery()) when I removed the sql closing semi-colon, so thnx @logworthy.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the SQL statement (which seems to appear in it's entirety in the error message), we see:

```
    '\nselect\n    UW_NET_ULTIMATE_LOSS_USD,\n    UW_NET_WRITTEN_PREMIUM_USD,\n    
IF UW_NET_WRITTEN_PREMIUM_USD = 0 THEN testvar=0 ELSE testvar=1 end\n
from bqiread.POLICY_METRICS\nwhere ROWNUM<100;\n
```

There's no CASE statement here....it apprears to be an IF/THEN/ELSE, which is not valid Oracle syntax.

Perhaps your tool is generating SQL for a different RDBMS than Oracle, and attempting to execute it in Oracle?

Comment: I agree that this discrepancy needs to be addressed by the OP. As a heavy, daily user of RODBC to connect to Oracle, I would consider it highly unusual for RODBC to be generating incorrect SQL, or for the error message to not reflect the query that was actually passed to it.

Comment: Joran- As a daily user, do you ever incorporate CASE WHEN statements? Do you query from Oracle?

Comment: @Tim_K Yes, frequently. I almost never work in Oracle directly. I query it via either RODBC or ROracle. And I use case statements all time.